# What does this quote from The New Yorker mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What does this bold part mean:

> The man who, as one author put it, “ruled the literary world from a fifteen-square-metre office” led a life more full of pain, wonder, and irony than most literary heroes. Born in Poland in 1920, Reich-Ranicki was sent to Berlin to study as a boy. “**With every year that he discovered more joy in, and love for, Thomas Mann and Brecht and Gründgens and Goethe, there also grew hate,**” wrote Frank Schirrmacher, publisher of the influential F.A.Z., where Reich-Ranicki headed the literature section in the nineteen-seventies and eighties. “**The hate of an entire nation and all its bureaucracy for the young Jewish man who just wanted to go to the Deutsche Theatre.**”
>
> [The New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/books/2013/09/marcel-reich-ranicki-obituary-literary-critic.html)

Answer (score 5):

I think the author of this passage confuses you by breaking a very long but continuous quotation into two parts. It works like this:

> With every year
>       that he discovered more [joy and love for these guys] (*this is a relative clause modifying "year"*)
>       there also grew hate—
>           —hate of [those other guys] for [him]

Year by year, while Reich-Ranicki was growing in love for his literary idols, the rest of the nation was growing in hatred for people like Reich-Ranicki.